# How to compare two strings with the same letter and different number?

Tags: python

I have two strings "s1" and "s2"

Is there any way that I can get a result like "s1" is greater than "s2" without changing the two values?

Comment: `>>> not('s1' > 's2')` ? I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Can you expand on what kinds of inputs you expect to have? Will the input always be exactly one letter and one number, or can it be something else?

Comment: What order do you want to impose on these strings? Should `'a1'` be greater or less than `'b1'`? What about `'a2'` and `'b1'`?

Comment: What do you want to *do* with the order you define? Sort the strings?

Comment: @warwaruk I made a terrible mistake, I thought strings are uncomparable with it's value, but I test myself, I'm wrong. Sorry for all the attentions draw by this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `>` or `<` ..

```
>>> 's1' > 's2'
False
>>> 's1' < 's2'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. See below:

```
s1 = "abcdefg"
s2 = "abcdefghijklmnop"

if len(s1) > len(s2):
    print("String 1 is longer than String 2")
elif len(s1) < len(s2):
    print("String 2 is longer than String 1")
else:
    print("String 1 and 2 are the same length.")
```

This will compare the lengths of the string s1 and s2. If this is not what you're looking for, then I'm not sure.